# Flink checkpointing failing in Kubernetes with FsStateBackend

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming, flink-sql

I am getting the error as stated below while using flink in kubernetes with per job state backend of FsStateBackend like so -: `env.setStateBackend(new FsStateBackend("file:///data/flink/checkpoints"))`

I am setting it in my code itself.

Error -:
`Mkdirs failed to create file:/data/flink/checkpoints/3321ab76ccf319397f5b52be25f6cd8d`
Can someone suggest resolution for this -:

Thanks in advance. Cheers!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to what @chuckskull pointed out, also make sure that this file URI is accessible to every pod in your cluster. All of the task managers and the job manager have to be able to read and write the checkpoint files using this URI.

Comment: It's important that not only JM has to have mounted checkpoint dir

Answer (score 0):

Here are a couple of things you can check:

- Make sure that `/data/flink/checkpoints` exists.
- Make sure that the user running the flink job has read/write access to this directory.